# Trying to run first COBOL .EXE in Windows, the CMD window closes after the second entry

Tags: cobol

I have just installedOpenCobolIDE 4.7.6 on a Windows 7 Pro PC.

My first program is a simple multiplier: http://www.csis.ul.ie/cobol/examples/Accept/MULTIPLIER.CBL

When I compile and run this program it has no errors.

When I run my Prog1.EXE, the Cmd window opens and prompts for the first number, and then a second number as expected.
When <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed after the second number, the CMD windows instantly closes before displaying the result.

I have tried adding this code line, before STOP RUN. But doesn't make any difference.

```
DISPLAY "Press Enter to End : "
STOP RUN.
```

Comment: Try adding an ACCEPT statement before the STOP RUN.  DISPLAY does not pause the program.

Comment: You could start a separate CMD in your directory and then start your compiled program in it.

Comment: Both comments above are actual solutions. In any case if you use OCIDE in Win7: ensure to update the contained GnuCOBOL to a current version (replace the folder "gnucobol" with a 3.1-version from https://www.arnoldtrembley.com/GnuCOBOL.htm [where the old version that OCIDE ships came from, too]). If you do so and have any "pending display" you'll by default see a "press any key to exit the program" message for this code.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these two lines to your code:

```
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    DISPLAY "Enter first number  (1 digit) : " WITH NO ADVANCING.
    ACCEPT Num1.
    DISPLAY "Enter second number (1 digit) : " WITH NO ADVANCING.
    ACCEPT Num2.
    MULTIPLY Num1 BY Num2 GIVING Result.
    DISPLAY 'Result is = ', Result.
    **DISPLAY 'Press <Enter> to continue'.**
    **ACCEPT Num2.**
    STOP RUN.
```